# Query order by ASC in google spreadsheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a google spreadsheet that uses the following query:

> ***=query('Respostas do Formulário 1'!A1:AG;"select D,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF WHERE
>   B='7ºA' order by D ASC";1)***

However column D from sheet: **"Respostas do Formulário 1"**, has values with a number then a name in front and when it performs the query in **sheet1** I wanted it to order ASC, like 1, 2,3,.., 10, 11,12..
But as you see in the image that is not happening...

[image]

Is there anyway I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

If you always have a hyphen (-) after the number, you could try extracting the number and sorting on it before doing the query:

```
=query(sort(A:A,value(left(A:A,(search("-",A:A)-1))),true),"Select  Col1 where Col1<'999'")
```

(change ranges to suit).

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert strings to numbers:

- `1 - xxxxx` to `1`
- `10 - yyyy` to `10`
- ...

Strings are sorted as a string: `"1", "10", "11", ..., "2", ..., "22", "23", ...`

Means they are sorted by the first char, then the second and so on.

---

Solution #1 is to make an extra column in your data sheet and extract numbers with a formula like `REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"^\d+")*1`.

Solution #2 is to get numbers on the fly. Heres sample formula:

`=QUERY(FILTER({REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"^\d+")*1,A:C},B:B="a"),"select * order by Col1")`

[image]

Notes:

- The formula uses the filter to combine the array. Filter limits the range to only rows needed.
- `{}` in a filter is used to combine the array.
- `REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"^\d+")*1` will give the column of numbers. `^` means the beginning of a string, `\d` means digit, `+` means one or more. `*1` is to convert the string `"10"` into the number `10`
- The query uses `Col1` notation because the source is an array.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having the problem of QUERY function sorting lexicographically a numerical column, I solved it by selecting an apropiate format in the numerical column so the numerical order coincides with the lexicographical order.

### Example

Suppose the column B has 2 digit integers (i.e. numbers form 0 to 99)

By adding the personalized number format "0#" in the column B, the numbers are displayed as 01, 02, 03, ..., 99. So the formula

```
=query(A1:B100,"SELECT * ORDER BY B ASC")
```

Works as one would like.

This requieres knowing the numbers of digits in advance. For numbers from 0 to 1000, the format would be "00#"